# Obtaining cancellation tokens in Async.FromContinuations declarations

Tags: f#, cancellation-token

Consider the following definition

```
let test =
    Async.FromContinuations(
        fun (cont,econt,ccont) ->
            let rec inner () =
                async {
                    do printfn "looping..."
                    do! Async.Sleep 1000
                    return! inner ()
                }

            Async.Start(inner ())
            cont ())
```

Suppose I want to try the computation like so

```
let cts = new CancellationTokenSource ()
Async.Start(test, cts.Token)
cts.Cancel()
```

This will naturally not make the inner loop stop, since I have not passed the suitable cancellation token. Is there any way I can obtain the outer cancellation token through Async.FromContinuations? I could rewrite this using the async builder and Async.CancellationToken, but then I would lose the ability to pass continuations to the inner expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

smth like this?

```
let test =
    async {
        let! ct = Async.CancellationToken
        return! Async.FromContinuations(
            fun (cont,econt,ccont) ->
                let rec inner () =
                    async {
                        do printfn "looping..."
                        do! Async.Sleep 1000
                        return! inner ()
                    }

                Async.Start(inner (), cancellationToken = ct)
                cont ())
    }
let cts = new CancellationTokenSource ()
Async.Start(test, cts.Token)
cts.CancelAfter(1000)
```

Comment: Don't forget to dispose the CTS, perhaps by shoving it under a use clause in async.

Comment: @toyvo Agreed - missing `Dispose` is bad. But shouldn't the CTS be disposed by the caller (who created it)? Probably after the `cts.Cancel()` call? (I would think that calling `Dispose` inside async could be wrong.)

Comment: @TomasPetricek yes, you are right. I was thinking of a case when you'd want to release the CTS when the async finishes, but then you also need to make sure Cancel is not called after Dispose; it requires a bit more code.

Answer (score 3):

Can you describe what are you trying to do? If I understand your code correctly, you want to start the `inner` loop function in the background and then, in parallel, continue running the rest of the workflow (using the `cont()` call).

To do this, you do not need `Async.FromContinuations`. There is a function that does *exactly this* and it also takes care of handling exceptions, cancellation tokens etc.

I think you could rewrite your program like this:

```
let test = 
    // The inner loop function from your example
    let rec inner () = async { 
        do printfn "looping..." 
        do! Async.Sleep 1000 
        return! inner ()  } 

    async { 
      // Start the inner loop as a child async 
      let! _ = Async.StartChild(inner())
      // ... continue doing other things in parllel if you wish
      do printfn "main body running..." }
```

Starting and cancelling of the computation looks as before:

```
let cts = new CancellationTokenSource () 
Async.Start(test, cts.Token) 
// This will cancel the 'inner' loop as well
cts.Cancel()
```

If you call `Async.StartChild` using `let!` then it will start the inner task, pass it the cancellation token etc. It returns a token that you can use later to wait until the child task completes, but since you're not doing that, I used the `_` pattern.

Comment: I was looking for a way to obtain the cancellation token when defining workflows from continuations, in a similar fashion as the primitive declarations in FSharp.Core that make use of the internal AsyncParamsAux type. So the inner code I gave in the post is basically just filler. I guess wrapping an Async.FromContinuations declaration into an async {} expression is good enough for that purpose.